# VS2017 Xamarin debugger not attaching in middle of program

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

Hi when I am trying to debug by running program with F5 then debugger working correct but not able to attach process to debugger in middle of application

Please help

Comment: Please the error message you are getting

Comment: I am not getting any error. When I am starting debugger by clicking F5 button its debugging and workign fine. My requirement is I want to attach debugger in middle of work.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately
, the debugger does not support attaching after the program has started (the Mono debugger does have a deferred attach mode but this isn't supported on iOS/Android).

Comment: I am not using Net Standard. I am using library project but start up project is android project. When we are running through F5 then debugger starting from start and its working fine. But I want to attach it in middle

Comment: Do you want attach debugger to process on device? did I understand you correctly?

Comment: Yes I want to add debugger to process on device or emulator